# Show that in every tree, there is a vertex $v$ $d(v) \geq 2$ that is adjacent to $k \geq d(v) -1$ leaves

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

Is my proof right?:

If the maximum degree is $2$ then is trivial since every tree has at least 2 leaves.
So if the maximum degree is $M \geq 3$ then we take the longest path in the tree, if the length is $2$ then $T$ is a star and we are done.
If not then in $P= \{x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ We have that $x_0$ and $x_n$ are leaves and the vertex adjacent can have degree $2$ in which case we are done or bigger than this.
So we can check for $N(x_1)$ since the path has a length greater than $2$ then the number of leaves adjacents is at most $|N(x_1)| - 1$ if thats the case then we are done, if not then there is a vertex adjacent to $x_1$ lets say $y$ wich is not a leaf, but then there is $w \neq x_1,w \in N(y)$ such that there is a path $P_1 = \{w,y,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ this path has length bigger than $P$.So we have a contradiction therefore there is a vertex $v$ adjacent to at least $d(v) -1$ leaves.

Edit:
I should been said $w$ not in $P$

Comment: Since every tree has a leaf $v$, with $d(v) = 1$, which is adjacent to atleast $0$ leaves. I think you meant an _internal_ vertex.

Comment: thanks, i edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a path $x_0 - x_1 - x_2 - x_3$, with $x_0, x_3$ as leaves. You're looking at $x_1$. Sure enough, you find a node adjacent to $x_1$ which is not a leaf, that is $x_2$. But you can't take this, 'cause then your new "path" would *no longer be a path*.

I guess that makes your proof incorrect.

But you can continue like this. You take $x_1$. That is certainly adjacent to a non-leaf node. We aim to prove that there is exactly one, that is $u = x_2$. That would prove the result.But suppose there were two, $u, u'$. Now since this is a tree, you can delete node $x_1$, creating two new trees $T, T'$, with $u \in T$ and $u' \in T'$ in different trees. Take the longest path containing $u'$ in $T'$, and "join" that with $x_1$ and the remainder of the longest path you found, $u = x_2, ...$. This is surely longer than the earlier longest path, creating a contradiction.

Comment: but i would only need to add $w$ not in the path, then, right?

Comment: Then your "path" would have $x_2$ adjacent to three vertices $w, x_3, x_1$, and would no longer remain a path.

Comment: but i would still be adjacent to $x1$ and in a tree the trajectories in a tree are unique, is the same you are saying, in this case $w$ would belong to the tree $T"$

Comment: See, you wanted a path like $w - y - x_1 - x_2 - .. $. But if $y = x_2$, then $w$ is adjacent to $x_2$, so your structure in which the edges are $x_1 - x_2, x_2 - x_3, x_2 - w ...$, is no longer a path, in which every vertex has degree $\leq 2$. $x_2$ would have degree $3$ in your path.

Comment: Oh now i understand i should said $y$ not in $P$ also, thanks

Comment: Yeah, $y$ shouldn't be in $P$ as well, for this to work.